# Use Singleton for model OR where to inject model into viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Normally I'd just use a singleton pattern for the model class Logbook.  However, I'm trying to move towards learning about DI and want to inject the model into my viewmodel.  In addition, I'm planning on having different child windows that open for various function (choose which logbook entries to display, sort order, add a logbook entry, etc) that may or may not need access to the model.  What are the pros and cons of using the singleton pattern vs DI with these constraints?  In addition, is DI possible if a lot of my viewmodels need access to this model?  Finally, where/how should I instantiate the view, viewmodel, and model to be able to inject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using dependency injection, the idea is to *provide* classes with a specific implementation of the dependency it needs, so when you're unit testing, you can provide a mock or stub implementation. This is known as loose coupling.

Singletons, meanwhile, are global state that you have no control over. If your class accesses a singleton, it's tightly coupled to the singleton. How do you mock a singleton? In general, you don't. You're stuck to it, and suddenly you have untestable code. Singletons are generally considered an anti-pattern for exactly this reason. (Aside: there *are* ways around that, but the basic design problem still exists)

Even worse, if something in your class mutates the state of the singleton, this can have side effects in other tests you're writing and make it very difficult to figure out why Test B passes when run alone, but fails if it's run after Test A.

My rule of thumb is **Don't use singletons, ever**.

Your specific question sounds a little bit fishy. Your viewmodel shouldn't need a model injected into it. It sounds like you want a class responsible for retrieving or otherwise constructing your model, and then you'd inject an implementation of that class into your viewmodel.

Comment: Okay that's what I was thinking.  To answer the last part, I need access to the model in viewmodel so I'm thinking DI is the best way of doing this.  Maybe I'm mistaken here?  This article may be helpful.  Note how the viewmodels have access to the customerRepository (this is what I'm trying to achieve).  The article just doesn't explain how this is achieved. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx